# Does Novell's Mono promote bloat in programs?

Tags: mono

Is Mono and/or Mono-based software bloatware? 
Eg: Banshee, Moonlight, Docky, Tomboy Notes, etc.
Is there anything actually wrong with software using Mono and/or Mono itself, or is it nothing more than an ethics issue?

Comment: Ethics? I'm afraid I don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

Mono is a free software implementation of an open EMCA standard.

Features include:

- JIT (just in time compiling)
- Garbage collection and memory management
- Type safety

Together these features help to provide a more reliable, safer program with less likelihood for memory leaks.

This comes at the cost of a small and efficient shared runtime.

Having said that software bloat is much more about how you use a language then what the language actually is.

I'm not sure how ethics is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been raised over and over again. Let me take a bold step and attempt to bury it.

Firstly C#, Boo, IronPython etc, are all just languages. The VM they run on introduces a thin layer, which in the case of modern systems is practically negligible. If a programmer writes well done, efficient code, then the application should in essence run as any native program would; smoothly, cleanly. Also, it should not introduce extra bloat; in fact sometimes the binary size on disk may be smaller.

In essence, the argument is pointless. Mono, Python, Perl, Java - etc, they are not bloatware. They are software.

What is bloatware? Badly written software.